# PC Freezes/Monitor turns off when I start with my GPU connected

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, freeze, gpu

I'm having an issue the last couple of days:

When I start up the PC and the monitor is connected to the GPU, it will turn itself off or PC will freeze within like 1-2 minutes of starting Windows. However, if I start the PC with monitor connected to the motherboard (iGPU), let it boot to Windows, and then unplug the monitor from iGPU and connect it to the GPU, it will work fine all day.

Things I did: newest drivers from NVIDIA, newest BIOS flashed, swapped PSU, reinstalled Windows 10.

Event audit gives me:
The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x00000116 (0xffffdd8925980010, 0xfffff80234d4f600, 0xffffffffc000009a, 0x0000000000000004).

Is this a hardware of software issue?

Forgot to add, this issue is only when cold booting PC. Restarting does not cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Bug Check 0x116: VIDEO_TDR_FAILURE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x116---video-tdr-failure) means:

> an attempt to reset the display driver and recover from a timeout has failed

It seems as if your GPU on a cold restart doesn't respond,
so the driver goes into timeout.

Since this doesn't happen when restarting on a warm reboot,
the usual explanation is that there is a weak contact somewhere.
When the computer has been turned on for some time, whatever
contact warms up and expands the little bit that is enough
to improve the contact.

I can't say which contact, but I suggest to reseat the GPU while
cleaning all contacts. Try to press all the contacts involved
in the display to ensure they are well-seated.

If you find nothing, perhaps a professional could find out more.